# Polygons are not closed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I noticed when drawing polygons with the Drawing Manager they are not closed (i.e. no coordinates for the last point to the first)..  I know Google Maps API v3 will automatically close the polygon but Google Earth, Google Static Maps API or any other software I try to import the data into..

My problem is, I use the geometry lib to save encoded polygons..  Is there any way to push a copy of the first point to the last in the overlays object before encoding?

My work around is to getPaths().getArray() to my own array, make the copy and then use a javascript lib to encode which works ok but is a lot of code..  Just wondering if there is an easier way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should add the first point of the polygon to the end of the [MVCArrry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray) (not tested).

```
myPoly.getPath().push(getPath().getAt(0));
```

(assumes a simple polygon with one path, [getPath](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) returns the first path)

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know you could so this.. :)  Ended up getting paths to a temp var and then pushing that.. tmp = mapOverlays[i].getPath().getAt(0);    mapOverlays[i].getPath().push(tmp);

Comment: @Dennis. V3 polygon violates industry standards (e.g. OGC). Note case (2) does not behave the same as (1) and (3). (1) Newly drawn V3 polygons *lack* the closing vertex in path. (2) Imported V2 polygons (with closing vertex) if unedited *retain* closing vertex in path. (3) Imported V2 polygons if edited *lack* the closing vertex in path. 
(4) I did not test google.maps for standards regarding the ring orientation: outer ring counterclockwise, inner ring clockwise. Note geometry/geography libraries have functions for correcting invalid ring orientation.